# I want to update my xml column in the database using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

Hi All 
Is been while since I am trying to figuare out how to update my xml Column in my SQLServer Table. Ok for clear understanding I want to increment each and every id by 1.
Ok this is my Tablename called Setting(SettingId int pk, Name nVarchar(100), XmlSetting xml)

//my data.xml

```
<setting>
<a id=1/>
<b id=2/>
<c id=22>
</setting>
```

My C# code for Incrementing this code is below

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();


private void SetAttribute(System.Xml.XmlNode node)//this code is running in the memory
  {

     System.Xml.XmlElement element = node as System.Xml.XmlElement;

      if (element != null)
            {
                int attributeCount = element.Attributes.Count;

                for (int i = 0; i < attributeCount; i++)
                {
                    System.Xml.XmlAttribute attribute = element.Attributes[i];

       if (string.Compare(attribute.Name, "Id", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                    {
                        int value;
                        if (int.TryParse(attribute.Value, out value))
                        {
                            attribute.Value = (value + 1).ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            attribute.Value = "1";
                        }
                    }
                }
                int childNodeCount = element.ChildNodes.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < childNodeCount; i++)
                {
                    SetAttribute(element.ChildNodes[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        public void EditXmlFile()
        {
            xdoc.Load(FILE_NAME);
            SetAttribute(xdoc.FirstChild);
            return;
        }
```

All what I am asking for is to update this code into my Database table Setting

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("connectionPath");

SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("Update Setting set SettingXml=@Settingxml where settingId=5",cnn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SettingXml","")//this where I am stacked because I am failing
        try
        {
           cnn.Open();
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            lblmsg.Text = "Error updating Xml " + ex.Message;
        }
```

}

How can update I update this SettingXml column with the above function because I want to increment every id by 1

Comment: honestly, your formatting is pretty messed up...

Comment: This is his 2nd question ever on SO. Cut him some slack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the updated XML as a string to your `SqlParameter`, so something like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("Update Setting set SettingXml=@SettingXml where settingId=5",cnn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SettingXml", SqlDbType.Xml)).Value = xdoc.OuterXml;
```

You might find it easier using Linq to XML for updating your XML going forward - `XmlDocument` is not very easy to use.

Also your current XML is not valid - let's assume it looks like this:

```
<setting>
  <a id="1"/>
  <b id="2"/>
  <c id="22"/>
</setting>
```

Then you can increment your id's using Linq to XML like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
doc.Root
   .Elements()
   .ToList()
   .ForEach(node => node.Attribute("id").Value = (Convert.ToInt32(node.Attribute("id").Value) + 1).ToString());

string xml = doc.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for Such a valuable information,unfortunetely I cannot able to access SetAttribute(System.Xml.XmlNode node) after trying to update on this line cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SettingXml", SqlDbType.Xml)).Value = xdoc.OuterXml; and on the XDocument doc=XDocument.Load("test.xml")..... .ForEach(node => node.Attribute("id").Value = (Convert.ToInt32(node.Attribute("id").Value) + 1).ToString());

Answer (score 0):

This would be so much easier if you used LINQ.  As @BrokenGlass pointed out the Linq to XML makes updating the XML much cleaner, and Linq to SQL will make your database update much cleaner also.  It should look something like this.

```
var dbContext = new MyDbContext();
dbContext.Settings.First(s => s.id == 5).XmlSetting = doc.Elements().First();
dbContext.SubmitChanges();
```

You should really spend some time learning Linq as it will make things like this so simple.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks man for your effort I really need to give myself time to study and impliment LinQ to SQL it look very easy but I didn't try to use it because time was not on my site. Thanks again